# Switching html pages inside the same (one) container html page

Tags: iframe, href, embed

Ok let us say I have just one HTML page. Call it index.htm
This is the container page.(Is there another fancy name for container page ?)

I have 3 buttons on this page on top.  Buttons A, B and C

If I click on Button A,  I want to display a HTML page called fileX.htm inside the same index.htm page, right below it. But then if I click on Button B, I want to replace fileX.htm with file fileY.htm (in the same area where fileX.htm was displayed). Then if I click on Button C, I want to replace fileY.htm with fileZ.htm. Then I click on button B and filey.htm must replace fileZ.htm on so on.

I know how to do this with iFrames. I have also seen this done using tabs and  a CSS file.
Both seem messy.

I know how to show just one file fileX.htm using embed tag.But the problem is switching from filex.htm to fileY.htm etc.
Is it possible to do this using embed or some other simple way such as an altered href tag or something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by changing `src` attribute of `embed` when the button is clicked using Javascript

Edit: Working example

index.html

```html
<embed type="text/html" src="test1.html" width="500" height="300" id="embed" />

<button id="test1">Test1</button>
<button id="test2">Test2</button>

<script>
  const test1 = document.getElementById("test1");
  const test2 = document.getElementById("test2");
  const embed = document.getElementById("embed");

  test1.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    embed.src = "test1.html";
  });

  test2.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    embed.src = "test2.html";
  });
</script>
```

test1.html

```html
<h1>test1</h1>
```

test2.html

```html
<h1>test2</h1>
```

You can do the same with object and iframe AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not too familiar with Javascript. Can you give an example on my above problem if you can please

Comment: I tried button click function in html & javascript with object tag & embed tag. No luck. I can launch new html page  by clicking a button but that new page kills the original page

Comment: @hura9 Edited the answer with an example

Comment: Hello whygee,  Your code in your second answer  worked perfectly. Thanks.  I would never have figured it out as I have not done much Javascript , especially in a long while.  I know how to do this is iFrames but it seems messy & as I have no experience with CSS, it was harder (I had my website in CSS with tabs & seemed to be a pain, who knows I may go back to iFrames or CSS again LOL) . The object tag I think is relatively new (probably in HTML 5).  Makes me wonder then what is the difference between object tag & embed tag and when to use them or not to use them.   Anyway thanks again

Comment: no worries. Please consider marking my answer as accepted (the check mark under) if it fully answers your question.